# How do I convert several large text files into one CSV file if they are too large to be converted individually?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have several large .text files that I want to consolidate into one .csv file. However, each of the files is to large to import into Excel on its own, let alone all together.

I want to create a use pandas to analyze the data, but don't know how to get the files all in one place.

How would I go about reading the data directly into Python, or into Excel for a .csv file?

The data in question is the [2019-2020 Contributions by individuals](https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data) file on the FEC's website.

Comment: if files don't headers and they have the same columns in the same order then you could simply concatenate file - even with system command - on linux something like like `cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv > output.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each of the files to csv and the concatenate them to fom one final csv file

```py
import pandas as pd
csv_path = 'pathtonewcsvfolder'                    # use your path
all_files=os.listdir("path/to/textfiles")
x=0
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_fwf(filename)
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_path,'log'+str(x)+'.csv'))
    x+=1
all_csv_files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(csv_path, "*.csv"))

converted_df=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_csv_files), ignore_index=True)
converted_df.to_csv('converted.csv')
```

Comment: I copied the path file directly from the folder, but am getting a message that the "system cannot find the path specified: 'Users\\Allie\\Documents\\Individual Contribution Data' "

Comment: try:  os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents\\Individual Contribution Data') `